# Gin Gonic array of values from PostForm

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm trying to capture an array of Post values from HTML form using Go / Gin Gonic -- in PHP I would use something like:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mygo">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email1@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email2@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email3@email.com">
</form>
```

However this doesn't seem to work with Gin Gonic (or Go for that matter).

I've also tried:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mygo">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email1@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email2@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email3@email.com">
</form>
```

As elsewhere it is suggested that doing this would cause `c.PostForm("emails")` to return a slice.  However in practice it seems that this instead returns the last value as a string instead :(

Interestingly, `c.Request.PostForm` returns an empty map, even if `c.Request.ParseForm()` is called first.  What am I doing wrong?

Go Form:

```
func main() {
// ...
    router.POST("mygo",parseFunc)
}

func mygo(c *gin.Context) {
  c.Request.ParseForm()
  log.Printf("%v",c.Request.PostForm["emails"]) // ""
  log.Printf("%v",c.PostForm("emails") // "email3@email.com"
}
```

Comment: To get multiple values, you need to use the `Request.Form` or `Request.PostForm` maps directly. If those aren't there please show a [mcve]. For instance, the form you show will submit via a _GET_ to the same url that generated the form.

Comment: @JimB - Edited to show MCV example :)

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to create a more complete example, because what you've shown should still work..

Comment: @JimB - Ah, I think my issues were two fold.  First c.Request.PostForm is likely not working at all because of something in my form that is not shown in the example `enctype="multipart/form-data"` .. Technically I don't think I need my form to be multipart and if I did I think it would just mean calling `ParseMultipartForm` rather than `ParseForm` -- `ParseMultipartForm` is however called when I call `c.PostForm` using gonic, but it appears the gonic method manually returns [only the first value](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/develop/context.go#L267-L269) - Will check and update.

Comment: The methods only returning the first value is expected, because that's how the std lib `http.Request` methods works.

Answer (score 8):

In order to make it works you have two ways here

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mygo">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email1@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email2@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email3@email.com">
</form>

r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Request.ParseMultipartForm(1000)
        for key, value := range c.Request.PostForm {
            fmt.Println(key,value)
        }
    })
```

either

```
    <form method="POST" action="mygo">
     <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email1@email.com">
     <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email2@email.com">
     <input type=hidden name="emails" value="email3@email.com">
    </form>

 r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Request.ParseForm()
            for key, value := range c.Request.PostForm {
                fmt.Println(key,value)
            }
        })
```

Both gives the same result

```
emails [email1@email.com email2@email.com email3@email.com]
```

Comment: Kudos for a general-purpose answer that will work in many other situations! However, I guess that the OP would prefer one of the other solutions that target specifically their own particular issue. Nevertheless, I found your trick quite useful for extracting _all_ form values, in those cases when I don't know beforehand how many there will be!

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of gin-gonic (v1.2) you can just:

```
emails := c.PostFormArray("emails")
```

Then `emails` will be a `[]string`.

`Parse` and `iterate` isn't more necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Issue with this code is two fold.  Posting my answer in case someone else has either of these problems.

1. `c.Request.PostForm` returns empty in this case because the form is multipart and `ParseForm` only parses non-multipart forms.  In order to get the data here either change the form type to non-multipart or call `ParseMultipartForm` before accessing post values.
2. `c.PostForm()` only returns the first value because thats what the wrapper in Gin Gonic does.  In order to access all the values, it is necessary to access the original `c.Request.PostForm` data, and then AFTER you parse it properly.

Thanks @JimB for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late about 5 years, but since I was searching for this also, I think it will still be useful for someone if I share my answer.

One of the simplest ways would be this:

in HTML

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mygo">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email1@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email2@email.com">
 <input type=hidden name="emails[]" value="email3@email.com">
</form>
```

in GO:

```js
emails, ok := c.Request.PostForm["emails[]"]
if ok {
    fmt.Println("this are your emails: ", emails)
}
```